# Calling sequential functions within a class in a single line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Apoligies if this has been answered anywhere, but I am unable to find the answer specific to my issue:

I have a class with several functions in that looks something like:

```
class myClass:
    def drawWhiteCanvas():
        # draws a blank white canvas
    def drawBlackCanvas():
        # draws a blank black canvas
    def drawSquare():
        # draws a square on the open canvas
    def drawTriangle():
        # draws a triangle on the open canvas
```

I can execute these functions separately like so:

```
myClass.drawWhiteCanvas()
myClass.drawTriangle()

or 
myClass.drawBlackCanvas()
myClass.drawSquare()
```

etc

and the result is as intended. A blank canvas is drawn and the shape is drawn on the canvas.

How can I execute these functions together though? e.g.:

```
myClass.drawWhiteCanvas().drawTriangle()
```

When I try to do this it gives a no attribute error. I have used other packages that allow execution of functions like this but cannot understand the source code to workout how it is done. Do my functions need to be outside the class or something?

Comment: The term you are after is ‘Fluent Interface’.

Comment: Are the methods `@staticmethod` ? because actual code doesn't work

Comment: I don't recommend doing this. Chaining functions gives the impression that each function returns a new object. If you call each function as its own statement, it's clear that you're doing side-effects without getting any new information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now you didn't specify any value to be returned from your method, so they return `None` and you can't call anything on that

```
myClass.drawWhiteCanvas().drawTriangle()
# is same as
x = myClass.drawWhiteCanvas()
x.drawTriangle()
```

You need to make your methods return the instance you call the method on, ie `self`

```
class myClass:
    def drawWhiteCanvas(self):
        # draws a blank white canvas
        return self

myClass().drawWhiteCanvas().drawTriangle()
```

If you don't want to instantiate an object, make them `classmethod`

```
class myClass:
    @classmethod
    def drawWhiteCanvas(cls):
        # draws a blank white canvas
        return cls

myClass.drawWhiteCanvas().drawTriangle()
```

Comment: Close, but since they're calling them as `myClass.func()` instead of `myClass().func()` they need to be class methods.